# xcode scheme does not have any option for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I started to have some issues with linker.

As I opened scheme for editing it changed from iPhone to Mac. I don't even have a choice of iPhone anymore. Perhaps my xcode is corrupted. I wonder if anyone had similar experience.

Comment: Try and exit project and reopen. I've seen issues when updating from source control when the project files are changed, switches from iOS Device to My Mac 64-bit. Close, reopen usually resolves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close project and restart Xcode. Open project and you should be as right as rain.